# Difference between BindingSource.Path and BindingSource.Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What's the difference between [`BindingSource.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindingsource.path?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [`BindingSource.Query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindingsource.query?view=aspnetcore-2.1)?

From what it seems non-complex values default to [`BindingSource.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindingsource.path?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but I can't really understand the difference between these two.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id) // id = BindingSource.Path
{
    return "value";
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This doesn't really explain much. I read that 20 times and I don't understand. Query string and request URL path are pretty ambiguous to me.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto wouldn't query string just be `?id=1` ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindingsource?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

> `BindingSource.Path`: A `BindingSource` for the request url path.

An URL path is normally in the format of `[controller]/[action]/{id?}`

> `BindingSource.Query`: A `BindingSource` for the request query-string.

An URL with a query-string is normally in the format of `[controller]/[action]?parameterName=parameterValue`.

As examples:

- `BindingSource.Path`: `http://localhost:1234/api/test/1`
- `BindingSource.Query`:`http://localhost:1234/api/test?id=1`